# Create n-dimensional matrix from a list of dimension values

Tags: arrays, matrix

I need to create an n-dimensional matrix containing all possible combinations of items from an arbitrarily sized list of arrays, in a generic way that can handle arbitrary sizes of both the list of "dimensions" and the number of values in each dimension.

For example, say my program is fed with this input:

```
type: d4, d6, d8, d12, d20
color: red, blue, golden
```

Then I will need to generate the following list of items:

```
red d4, red d6, red d8, red d12, red d20, blue d6, blue d8, blue d12, blue d20,
golden d4, golden d6, golden d8, golden d12, golden d20
```

I initially had a static code that works for two dimensions, but now I need to solve for 1~n dimensions.

Any standard programming language will do (i.e. please don't use magical functional languages that I will have no idea how to translate to my implementation), and even a free language description. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's analogous to how you increment a number. A decimal number for example has units, tens, hundreds. Now say your *units* are the types, your *tens* are your colors... but each digit may have different number of values.

So we map d4 to 0, d6 to 1, d8 to 2, d12 to 3, d20 to 4. We map red to 0, blue to 1, golden to 2. Let's start the counting:

```
00 => (d4, red)
01 => (d6, red)
02 => (d8, red)
03 => (d12, red)
04 => (d20, red)
10 => (d4, blue)
11 => (d6, blue)
...
```

So the algorithm increments the first digit unless it reached its biggest value, in which case we make it zero and we increment the second digit. If while incrementing the second digit, it has already its biggest value, then we make it zero and we move on to the third digit...

This is python code:

```
d = [
    ["d4", "d6", "d8", "d12", "d20"],
    ["red", "blue", "golden"]
]

n = len(d)  # n is number of dimensions
s = [0] * n  # Start with zeroes for each dimension
flag = True
while flag:
    # print tuple
    print ",".join(d[dimension][index] for dimension, index in enumerate(s))
    for dimension in xrange(n):
        s[dimension] += 1  # Increment dimension

        # Have we exchausted dimension values?
        if s[dimension] == len(d[dimension]):
            s[dimension] = 0  # Make 0 and move to next dimension
            flag = dimension < n - 1  # Have we exchausted all dimensions?
        else:
            break
```

Output:

```
4,red
d6,red
d8,red
d12,red
d20,red
d4,blue
...
d12,golden
d20,golden
```

Comment: This is eventually what I did, though the code to implement counter incrementation where each unit is arbitrarily sized isn't exactly trivial. Here's my algorithm: `let f be a map of dimension names to dimension values; let fk be a list of dimension names; let c be a zero-filled array the same size as fk; let r be an empty list; while (last(c) < size(f[last(fk)])) { r += (c => (i,n) { f[fk[i]][n] }); c[0] += 1; i = 0; while (i < size(c)-1 && c[i] >= size(f[fk[i]])) { c[i+1] += 1; for (j in 0..i) { c[j] = 0; }; i += i; } }`. whew. hope you can follow that :-)

Comment: JuniorCompressor - your code works fine, though I don't like the use of an external for loop that you break out of it when there is no overflow (which is most cases). I prefer using a loop just for the overflow - like in my algorithm, as it is generally more readable - though it does save on the end checking by having it simpler and run only when needed, and the total LOC is smaller though harder to understand.

Comment: Yes I don't disagree. In either case it's not sooooo difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion depth to take care of `n` (length of arrayofarrays).

```pl
sub sample {
    my $a = pop;
    return @_
      ? map {
        my $i = $_;
        map { [ @$i, $_ ] } @$a
      } sample(@_)
      : map { [$_] } @$a;
}
@aoa = ( [qw/i j k l m/], [qw/ a s d f g/], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 7, 3 ] );
use Data::Dumper;
@pk = sample(@aoa);
print Dumper \@pk;
print scalar @pk;
```

Python code:

```py
def sample(aoa):
    a = aoa.pop()
    return [[i] for i in a ] if len(aoa) == 0 else [ i+[j] for i in sample(aoa) for j in a]

#demo
aoa_in = [
       ["i", "j", "k", "l", " m"],
       ["a", "s", "d", "f", "g"],
       [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
       [ 7, 3 ]
      ]
import pprint
pp= pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
pp.pprint(sample(aoa_in))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. At first I couldn't get it to work because while it looks like you are using python's list comprehension syntax, the code doesn't actually compile with python. after massaging it a bit I got it working, and it returns a nice matrix for 2 dimensions, but returns something horrible for any dimension > 2.

Comment: Yep, this works and you made your point about using recursive list comprehension, though even though I know perl quite well, and you still put the "cryptic" in "perl code is cryptic" ;-)

Comment: :D guilty as charged. Glad that it does the needful. :)